# Getting java.lang.VerifyError: class waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator overrides final method start.()V on starting tomcat 8 server in eclipse

Tags: java

I tried to start the tomcat 8 server form eclipse .Then I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.VerifyError: class waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator overrides final method start.()V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1178)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
```

I have copied waffle-jna jar in tomcat lib folder. I copied this jar from the lib folder of tomcat 6 installation I had in my system. Is it a version issue ? Please help me in figuring out the reason for this.

Comment: Wrap your source of error with try/catch for potentially more information.

Comment: Yes, it's a version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a version issue.

The verifier is a part of the JVM that runs correctness checks on classes when they're loaded, and one check is that a class can't override final methods.

In this case, some superclass of `MixedAuthenticator` defines a `void start()` method that was not final in the version that `MixedAuthenticator` was compiled against but *is* final in the version you have at runtime. Presumably either the `MixedAuthenticator` has been updated not to override that method, or the superclass has been updated to make that method non-final. You need to match versions of `MixedAuthenticator` and whichever superclass is the problem here.

Note that issues like this are one reason it's preferable to package library jars with your project whenever possible instead of using the container global classpath.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of **VerifyError** is that you changed the definition of new class, but old class was compiled using an older version of the class.

In order to avoid the **VerifyErrorr**, you must compile all your classes using the same version of Java. Also, once you make a change to a class, then make sure that you re-compile your project from scratch. Finally, if your application makes use of external libraries, verify that you use the appropriate version of every library and of course, consult the corresponding javadocs, in order to be sure that everything is correct.

need to check which class you are compiling that isn't present in the classpath elsewhere in your application, maybe in another jar?

Also, need to check through your stacktrace, is the character encoding of the source file (utf-8?) correct?

Comment: It's not about Java version. It's about catalina library version supplied with tomcat.